# Закрыть bootstrap dropdown меню по клику на ссылку внутри

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Какие есть варианты сделать ссылку "назад" внутри для bootsrap dropdown menu ?

```js
$('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).dropdown('toggle');

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"> <<< - Back</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пробую `dropdown('toggle')`.

Сейчас выдает ошибку:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
>       at Object.onLoad (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js:4:20970)
>       at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js:4:14236
>       at Array.forEach () ....

Comment: Подскажите, а какая задача у Вас стоит? Какая необходимость использовать `dropdown` в выпадающем списке? При клике "назад" Вы хотите закрыть список, или перейти на предыдущую страницу?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, хочу просто закрыть без ошибок

Comment: Так, если Вы будете использовать ссылку без перевода на другую страницу, при клике на эту ссылку и так закроется выпадающее меню. Или Вы хотите как-то вне этого меню иметь возможность его закрывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина была в том, что не на ту ссылку обрабатываю (нужно не внутреннюю, а внешнюю):

```
$('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).closest('.dropdown-toggle').toggle();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dropdown` меню, в Вашем случае и так закрывается при клике на любую ссылку внутри него. 
Если же Вы хотите прям закрыть меню при нажатии на ссылку, то можете использовать просто удаление класса `show` у `dropdown`.

```js
$('.dropdown-item .dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).classList.remove('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown link
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"> <<< - Back</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня теперь такая ошибка: main.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Comment: @user3178479 Подскажите, Вы корректно скопировали код `js`? Может у Вас тогда несколько кнопок с таким классом `.dropdown-item .dropdown-toggle`. Ошибка сообщает, что у `dropdown` меню в этот момент нет класса `show`. То есть Вы нажимаете кнопку в тот момент, когда меню закрыто, или  есть такие же элементы с подобным же селектором.